# Deploying scala/lift app on cloudbees via git with sbt 0.11.3

Tags: git, scala, sbt, lift, cloudbees

I am getting started with a small app written in scala with lift on cloudbees. At the moment there is no scala involved, I just want to deploy a website in the static folder of the lift template. I created a build job on cloudbees with sbt but it gives the following error:

```
[error] {file:/scratch/jenkins/workspace/igem%20sbt/project/}default-81f689/*:update: 
sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.github.siasia#xsbt-web-plugin_2.9.1;0.12.0-0.2.11.1: not found
```

I can compile the app (also fetched from git) on my local machine via sbt->package and deploy it to cloudbees via "bees app:deploy". The files are also available on the workspace from git.

I use sbt 0.12 on my local machine and 0.11.3 on cloudbees (/opt/sbt/sbt-launch-0.11.3-2.jar). That is because I don't know how to find out which is the latest version on cloudbees or how i can use my own jar of sbt on cloudbees. I also don't know which config files I have to edit to adjust for 0.11.3 or if this is is the error after all. If I have to change that I also need to know how do downgrade on my local machine (OS X -> use homebrew).

Here the full error and my build.sbt: http://pastebin.com/bwAu1hGr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SBT is pretty brittle when it comes to plugin versions.  A separate jar of each plugin needs to be published for each SBT version, similar to Scala cross building.  If you are using different versions of SBT to build in different environments, that means that you either need to

- Use only plugin versions that are published for every SBT version you'll use or
- Dynamically choose the right plugin version in your plugins.sbt file, based on the SBT version in use.

Personally, I'd just standardize on a particular SBT version for your project and add the sbt-launch.jar file to your project along with a script that references it.  I haven't done much with Cloudbees, but with Jenkins you can configure an SBT launcher with a value like: ${WORKSPACE}/sbt-launch.jar.  That assumes that sbt-launch.jar is in the root of your git repo.

Answer (score 1):

Using arbitrary versions of sbt on CloudBees with the sbt-plugin is (pretty) easy:

1. go to Manage Jenkins
2. add a new sbt version in the sbt-plugin section called 'project-specific sbt' with a path of 'sbt-launch.jar'; this path will be relative to your project's workspace root and can be whatever you want -- I have a play2 project so I actually use 'project/sbt-launch.jar'
3. put a copy of the sbt-launch.jar into your project to align with the path in #3
4. re-configure your project build job to use the 'project-specific sbt' in the sbt-plugin drop-down
5. push your changes

This is essentially a refinement of Dave Whittaker's approach, but corrects the issue of using ${WORKSPACE}/sbt-launch.jar doesn't work because ${WORKSPACE} is not substituted by Jenkins.

The key change is to define a relative path to sbt-launch.jar into the project workspace because Jenkins performs the build from the root of the job's workspace.

P.S. Thanks, @dave-whittaker!  I used your answer to work-out my own build issues.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use the built in SBT if you don't want to - you can use a build step that uses a shell, and downloads the required version, if it isn't already cached in your workspace, and uses that one.

Using something like:

```
if [ ! -e $sbt ]
then
    wget $sbt_url 
    #install it
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Very inconvenient. Here are two workarounds for now. I successfully tried the first one.

**Select the correct sbt version in the plugin.sbt**

Based on http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/github/siasia/ i figured out the correct dependencies for each sbt version. So now i can run 0.12.1 on my local machine and 0.11.3 on cloudbees with the same file. I hope the other versions are correct too. I think if I would change scala version from 2.9.1 to 2.9.2 it might cause trouble again, because then you need 0.12.*

Here is what my project/plugin.sbt looks like

```
libraryDependencies <+= sbtVersion(v => v match {
case "0.11.0" => "com.github.siasia" %% "xsbt-web-plugin" % "0.11.0-0.2.8"
case "0.11.1" => "com.github.siasia" %% "xsbt-web-plugin" % "0.11.1-0.2.10"
case "0.11.2" => "com.github.siasia" %% "xsbt-web-plugin" % "0.11.2-0.2.10"
case "0.11.3" => "com.github.siasia" %% "xsbt-web-plugin" % "0.11.3-0.2.11.1"
case "0.12.0" => "com.github.siasia" %% "xsbt-web-plugin" % "0.12.0-0.2.11.1"
case "0.12.1" => "com.github.siasia" %% "xsbt-web-plugin" % "0.12.0-0.2.11.1"
})
```

**Upload the latest SBT plugin to cloudbees**

You could also upload files to a privat folder via WebDav (and only this way i think):

```
  https://repository-{account-id}.forge.cloudbees.com/private/
```

This way you could upload the sbt-launch-0.12.jar. Get this from (the template is also good to start a project):

```
  https://github.com/lift/lift_25_sbt/tree/master/scala_29/lift_basic
```

This I have not tested: Now you should configure the sbt in cloudbees. So login and:

```
 Builds->Manage Jenkins->Configure System
```

And add /private/{account-id}/{sbt-launch-your-version}.jar in the sbt section.

Answer (score 0):

CloudBees makes it easy to put your own tools on the build servers even though you can't ssh into them directly. You can use WebDav to upload the executables into a private repository that is mounted on each of your build machines. You can use this to upload a newer version of SBT and then reference it from the Jenkins SBT plugin.

See the "Private Repository" section of this page for more details on setting up your WebDav connection: http://wiki.cloudbees.com/bin/view/DEV/Custom+Build+Tools